# Chrome submitting the form without showing any pop-up notification when I click the back-button?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Chrome is now sucking day-by-day. I have an ASP.NET application. When a user perform a POST action. Then he click a link(GET action). Then click browser back button. Chrome is doing the POST action again. No issues in any other browser. Here is an example that any-one can confirm. Just click the POST button and then click the GET link and then click Back button. Create 2 WebForm pages,

**WebForm1.aspx**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="submit" value="POST" />
        <a href="WebForm2.aspx">GET</a>
    </form>
    Http Details:
    <%= Request.HttpMethod %>
    <%= DateTime.Now %>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm2.aspx**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="submit" value="POST" />
        <a href="WebForm1.aspx">GET</a>
    </form>
    Http Details:
    <%= Request.HttpMethod %>
    <%= DateTime.Now %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** I have added **DateTime.Now** above. Here is the observation,

```
Open WebForm1.aspx
Http Details: GET 9/24/2013 11:43:10 AM

Click Post Button,
Http Details: POST 9/24/2013 11:43:35 AM

Click GET Button(The Browser will redirect you too WebForm2.aspx),
Http Details: GET 9/24/2013 11:43:46 AM

Click Browser Back Button(The Browser will show WebForm1.aspx in address bar)
Http Details: POST 9/24/2013 11:44:17 AM
```

Comment: If you google something like 'chrome post back button' it seems like you're not the only one complaining about this behaviour

Comment: @Aristos, Yes Sorry I have checked. It was typo.

Comment: That bug is documented at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263508 .  Per the comments, it's fixed in the next version of Chrome (version 30).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often good practice to respond with a redirect from a post action:

1. browser POSTs form: return HTTP/302 with location X
2. browser GETs X: serve page X
3. browser reload will now do a GET X

Like this when that page is reloaded the page is served again without trying to post the form a second time.

That probably also solves the problem you have with this Chrome bug.

Comment: +1 this is always good practise. It also prevents issues with users reloaded a POSTed page and getting "do you want to re-submit the data" warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is still open with chromium. To know the status of this issue please check here.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263508

Meanwhile try as mentioned in the above answer